# Spark job crash with no space left on device because of hdfs "non DFS usage"

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, amazon-emr

I am running a spark sql job on a small dataset (25 GB) and I always end up filling up the disk of  things and eventually crashing up my executors.

```
$ hdfs dfs -df -h
Filesystem                 Size   Used  Available  Use%
hdfs://x.x.x.x:8020  138.9 G  3.9 G     14.2 G    3%

$ hdfs dfs -du -h
2.5 G    .sparkStaging
0        archive
477.3 M  checkpoint
```

When this append, I have to leave safemode.. `hdfs dfsadmin -safemode leave`

Looking at the spark job itself, it is obviously a problem of shuffle or caching dataframes.  However, any idea why `df` reports such irregular Used/Available sizes?  And why `du` does not list files?

I understand that it's related to the "non DFS usage" I can see in namenode overview. But why spark uses up so much "hidden" space to the point it makes my job crash?

```
Configured Capacity: 74587291648 (69.46 GB)
DFS Used: 476200960 (454.14 MB)
Non DFS Used: 67648394610 (63.00 GB)
DFS Remaining: 6462696078 (6.02 GB)
```

Comment: Looks like this is the temp folder of spark that is eating that much space.  In my case serialized dataframes are significantly bigger than original data and that fill up the disk when filtering, joining and processing.